# Is there a way to send captured packets without putting a new header on the packet?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm writing an application in C++ that requires me to simulate network traffic based on captured pcap data. I'm kind of new to networking so i was curious if there is a way to send the data AND original header i have over an eth interface without modifying the packet at all. I've sent data over the line using Raw sockets but the data is corrupted on the other side (it seems that the sendto is still altering the dest and source IP addresses). This application is being written on RHEL 6.9 in Qt Creator. any direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You may need to turn off the TCP-offloading (and similar) feature for your NIC. With TCP offloading the kernel doesn't have the final say in what goes over the wire - the NIC has its own opinion and mutates your data.